# Is the exponential function the one this problem is hinting at?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic on all of $\mathbb{C}$ and that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^nf(z)$$ exists, uniformly on compact sets, and that this limit is not identically zero. Then the limit function $F$ must be a very particular kind of entire function. Can you say what kind?

**My attempt/thoughts:**

Well if the limit function is $F$, then $$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(F(z)\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^nf(z)\right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^{n+1}f(z) = F(z).$$

Therefore, $$F'(z) = F(z) \implies F(z) = Ae^z$$

Where $A$ is some complex number.

However, this problem is supposed to be one of the harder problems, so my guess is that I must have assumed something that I shouldn't have. Is this wrong? If so, could you point out my error?

Comment: The convergence to the limiting $F(z)$ need not be uniform, and so it is not clear that you can interchange derivative and limit.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: The convergence is assumed to be uniform in compact sets, hence locally uniform. For holomorphic functions (but **not** otherwise), this yields (locally) uniform convergence of the derivatives, so the proof is fine. @ OP: I do not think you missed something, you just found the right "trick" to attack the problem.

Comment: @PhoemueX if you put that into an 'answer' form, I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: Your solution is correct. Interchange of $d/dz$ and $\lim$ is justified when the convergence is uniform on compact subsets.